# How to create a JSON based on HTML inputs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having some trouble creating a multi dimension json based on multiple html form inputs:

the html inputs:

```
<div class="form-group-attached m-b-10">
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="title">title</label>                      
<input type="text" name="title" value="some title" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group-attached m-b-10">
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="tile-icon input-group-addon d-flex">
<i class="fa-2x fa-color far fa-image"></i>                    </div>
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="image">Image URL</label>                      
<input type="text" name="image" value="some image url" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="tile-icon input-group-addon d-flex">
<i class="fa-2x fa-color far fa-link"></i>                    </div>
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="link">Link URL</label>                      
<input type="text" name="link" value="http://www.google.com" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
var frmData = {};
$(':input').each(function(){   
   frmData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
alert(JSON.stringify(frmData));
```

Here is the json what I am getting:

```
{"title":"some title","image":"some image url","link":"http://www.google.com"}
```

What I need instead is after 'title', I would like to create a data object and add everything else as an sub level of 'data' like so:

```
{"title":"some title","data":{"image":"some image url","link":"http://www.google.com"}}
```

any help is appreciated.

thank,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I would solve it:

```js
var inputToJson = function() {
 var formData = {};
 formData.data = {};
 $('input').each(function( index ) {
   if($( this ).attr('name')=="title") {
    formData[$( this ).attr('name')] = $( this ).val();
   }
   else {
    formData["data"][$(this).attr('name')] = $( this ).val();
   }
 });
 return formData;
}
console.log(inputToJson());
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><div class="form-group-attached m-b-10">
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="title">title</label>                      
<input type="text" name="title" value="some title" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group-attached m-b-10">
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="tile-icon input-group-addon d-flex">
<i class="fa-2x fa-color far fa-image"></i>                    </div>
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="image">Image URL</label>                      
<input type="text" name="image" value="some image url" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="tile-icon input-group-addon d-flex">
<i class="fa-2x fa-color far fa-link"></i>                    </div>
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="link">Link URL</label>                      
<input type="text" name="link" value="http://www.google.com" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It's important to note that the proper way to access data from a form is using .serialize() on the actual  element but given the special requirement of augmenting parts of the form within a custom "data" object that approach would also require additional manipulation.

[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vuzamiyuco/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: thank you. this worked. i had try the additional if then... but forgot to initialize the frmdata.data = {}

Answer (score 0):

The code below gives the output that you want. Just go through that.

```js
var frmData = {};
var frmDataImageArray = [];
var frmDataTitle;
var frmDataImage;
var frmDataLink;
$(':input').each(function(){   
if($(this).attr('name')=='image')
 frmDataImage=$(this).val();
else if($(this).attr('name')=='link')
 {
   //Here i assume that link is the last control in this form that's why i put this code here. So that title and image is fetched before entering into this statement
   frmDataLink=$(this).val();
   frmDataImageArray.push({"Image":frmDataImage,"Link":frmDataLink});
   //frmData={"title":frmDataTitle,"Data":{"Image":frmDataImage,"Link":frmDataLink}};
}
else
 frmDataTitle=$(this).val();

   //frmData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
frmData={"title":frmDataTitle,"Data":frmDataImageArray};
console.log(JSON.stringify(frmData));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group-attached m-b-10">
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="title">title</label>                      
<input type="text" name="title" value="some title" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group-attached m-b-10">
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="tile-icon input-group-addon d-flex">
<i class="fa-2x fa-color far fa-image"></i>                    </div>
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="image">Image URL</label>                      
<input type="text" name="image" value="some image url" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
<div class="tile-icon input-group-addon d-flex">
<i class="fa-2x fa-color far fa-link"></i>                    </div>
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="link">Link URL</label>                      
<input type="text" name="link" value="http://www.google.com" class="form-control">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Jino. I forgot to mention that 'image' and 'link' are dynamic and can be potentially different. Thus I did the .each function so that it would just iterate through. The only constant is 'title' input... all fields after 'title' should be within the 'data' json object.

Comment: Just run this code. Is this is the expected output that you want.

Comment: Do you want 'data' field on your JSON as an array of object?

Comment: Yes, as in {"title":"some title","data":{"image":"some image url","link":"http://www.google.com"}} so that i can later call this as data['image']... but not {"title":"some title","data":[{"image":"some image url","link":"http://www.google.com"}]} as this becomes data[0]['image']

Comment: Now I had just edited my answer. Now the JSON is in the format below {"title":"some title","Data":[{"Image":"some image url","Link":"http://www.google.com"}]}. Is this is the output that you want?.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
var frmData = {};
var Title;
var Image;
var Link;
$(':input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'image')
        Image = $(this).val();
    else if ($(this).attr('name') == 'link') {
        Link = $(this).val();
        frmData = {
            "title": Title,
            "Data": {
                "Image": Image,
                "Link": Link
            }
        };
        arr.push(frmData)
    } else
        Title = $(this).val();
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(frmData));//json format
console.log(arr);//arr fomat
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group-attached m-b-10">
    <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
        <div class="form-input-group">
            <label for="title">title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="some title" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group-attached m-b-10">
    <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
        <div class="tile-icon input-group-addon d-flex">
            <i class="fa-2x fa-color far fa-image"></i> </div>
        <div class="form-input-group">
            <label for="image">Image URL</label>
            <input type="text" name="image" value="some image url" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-default input-group required">
        <div class="tile-icon input-group-addon d-flex">
            <i class="fa-2x fa-color far fa-link"></i> </div>
        <div class="form-input-group">
            <label for="link">Link URL</label>
            <input type="text" name="link" value="http://www.google.com" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="generateJson">Generate Json</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is already in one of the previous answers, but as I am sitting in a train with nothing else to do I put together the following minimal solution:

```
var jsn={data:{}};
$('input','form:first').each(function(i,o){
  var na=$(o).attr('name');
  (na=='title'?jsn:jsn.data)[na]=o.value;
});
```

This can go into the `$(function( ... )}` section or be triggered by some click event. I am currently treating all inputs within the first `<form>` element on the page. You can change that to suit your needs.